# C# WCF Service Get Status Code

Tags: c#, wcf, httpresponse

I have a very basic WCF service which has a method named `SaveSchoolName(string SchoolName)` which basically returns as boolean value of True if the operation is good.
.
I added a service reference to my client application and is consuming the service as follows:

```
MyService.WebServicesClient svc = new MyService.WebServicesClient();
bool dataSaved = false;
dataSaved = svc.SaveSchoolName("School Name");

if(dataSaved){
  // do something.
}
else{
  // log not saved.
}
```

I want to know how do I determine the Http Status Code (200 - OK) for the WCF Service call. I have tried to search but none seems to provide any detailed info on how I would be able to get the response headers from invoking the method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a client message inspector for this.

Check the below code out ... to make it work just add the inspector to your client.  BTW, obviously this only works for HTTP :)

```
public class HttpStatusCodeMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        if (reply.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name))
        {
            var httpResponseProperty = (HttpResponseMessageProperty)reply.Properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name];
            Console.WriteLine($"Response status is {(int)httpResponseProperty.StatusCode}");
        }
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you mentioned it only works for HTTP, do you mean to say it would not work for HTTPS? Also, where do I invoke this message inspector?

Comment: No, I meant HTTP protocol, meaning it will work with HTTP/HTTPS/WebSockets.  As for how you invoke it .. you need to add the message inspector in your client channelFactory by means of an endpoint behavior.  This will automatically get executed every time the client receives a reply from the server.

Comment: A little confused on where i would add the code you provided. I am practically consuming the web service from code behind.

Comment: You need to add the message inspector on your client.  Your code is using ClientBase, so search for 'add wcf message inspector clientbase'.  For starters, read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730107(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @JorgeDelConde If I am using proxies created by svcutil, I'll have to add a new class -HttpStatusCodeMessageInspector? Any references would be helpful. I am looking at this - https://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector

Comment: To add the inspector to the client, you need to implement `IEndpointBehavior`. In the `ApplyClientBehavior()` method, you can add your inspector to `clientRuntime.MessageInspectors`. Then you add the object to the client this way: `client.Endpoint!.EndpointBehaviors!.Add(new EndPointBehavior());`

Answer (score 0):

To extend [@Jorge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42310009/7120031), I started by implementing the `IClientMessageInspector` and `IEndpointBehavior` from the [example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-inspect-or-modify-messages-on-the-client#example). I replaced the contents of `IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply` with the code provided by Jorge:

```cs
public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
{
    if (reply.Properties.ContainsKey(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name))
    {
        var httpResponseProperty = (HttpResponseMessageProperty)reply.Properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name];
        Console.WriteLine($"Response status is {(int)httpResponseProperty.StatusCode}");
    }
}
```

Now, you can choose to continue inheriting `BehaviorExtensionElement` and add the behavior to your client configuration file. If you take this approach you'll be done.

However, since my client configuration was created programmatically, I needed a few additional steps here.

In the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.description.serviceendpoint.behaviors?view=netframework-4.8) you can see that an Endpoint Behavior can be added by using the `ServiceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add` method. But how do we get access to the `ServiceEndpoint` object?

This can be done by first creating your service client object, and then using its `Endpoint` property like so:

```vb
''' VB.NET
'' Creating the binding obj
Dim objMyBinding As New System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding()
objMyBinding.Name = "YOUR_BINDING_NAME"
'' Other details of binding added here ''

'' Creating the endpoint address obj
Dim objMyEndpoint As System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress
objMyEndpoint = New System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(New Uri(ENDPOINT_ADDR_HERE))

'' Creating the Service obj
Dim objWebServices As CalculatorService = New CalculatorService(objMyBinding, objMyEndpoint)

'' Finally adding the behavior to the Service Endpoint (CustomEndpointBehavior is implementation of IEndpointBehavior)
objWebServices.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(New CustomEndpointBehavior)
```

```cs
/// C#.NET
// Creating the binding obj
System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding objMyBinding = New System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding();
objMyBinding.Name = "YOUR_BINDING_NAME";
// Other details of binding added here //

// Creating the endpoint address obj
System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress objMyEndpoint;
objMyEndpoint = New System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(New Uri(ENDPOINT_ADDR_HERE));

// Creating the Service obj
CalculatorService objWebServices = New CalculatorService(objMyBinding, objMyEndpoint);

// Finally adding the behavior to the Service Endpoint (CustomEndpointBehavior is implementation of IEndpointBehavior)
objWebServices.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(New CustomEndpointBehavior());
```